# SOAP API in drupal 7

Tags: web-services, api, soap, drupal, drupal-7

Am trying to consume SOAP API in drupal 7.

My current state is, I have one webform along with 10 different fields. So, when user enter their details and submit the form, action will trigger from Rules and the entered data should send through SOAP API to the external link(.asmx).

In this case, I couldn't able to find any contributed modules related with. Can anybody help it out in this case? since am newbie to SOAP API's.

What are the modules should I use?

Is any otherway to consume the data as SOAP API in drupal 7?

Any module converts the data as SOAP format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try the PHP SOAPClient extension, depending on the API you are trying to interact with, there may be a PHP wrapper for it already

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    $client = new SoapClient('http://url/to/xml.asmx', array('trace' => TRUE));
    $params = new stdClass(); 
    $params->whatever = 'whatever';
    $response = $client->methodName($params);
}
catch (SOAPFault $e) {
  // handle that 
}
```